# What does evaluating a definite integral where the limits are functions represent?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I understand that FTC claims:

$$ \int_a^bf(t)dt = F(b) - F(a) \text{ ,where a and b are functions}$$

What does $F(b) - F(a)$ mean/represent?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "$a$ and $b$ are functions". Please edit the question to show us the real problem you are trying to solve, not this abstract version. Include all necessary details.

Comment: perhaps OP means what if one were to make $a,b$ functions . what would $F(b) -F(a)$ mean under that context?

Comment: something like $ \frac{d}{dx} f(t) \Big|_{x^2+1}^{e^x} =  \frac{d}{dx} F(e^x) - F(x^2+1) = (f(e^x)e^x) - (f(x^2+1)2x)$

Answer (score 1):

If $F(x)$ is primitive function of $f(x)$ then $F'(x)= f(x)$ and $$\int_a^bf(t)dt= F(x)\Big|^b_a = F(b)-F(a)$$

Answer (score 0):

These stand for antiderivatives, that is $F' = f$. We can pick an arbitrary such antiderivative (why?).